# How to create layout having circle in background and images on top?

Tags: android, layout, responsive-design, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

**I am unable to make this layout with custom design**

Is there any library for this, are we have to do this is custom?

Kindly let me know how to do this. Here is the link of the image i am going to create the design same like this.

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sOLI.png

Comment: To get you started, take a look at [https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#CircularPositioning](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#CircularPositioning)

Answer (score -1):

You have to position it separately for each photo and prepare an oval dressing.

`layout_constraintCircle` : references another widget id
`layout_constraintCircleRadius` : the distance to the other widget center
`layout_constraintCircleAngle` : which angle the widget should be at (in degrees, from 0 to 360)

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonA" ... />
  <Button android:id="@+id/buttonB" ...
      app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/buttonA"
      app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"
      app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="45" />
```